# nginx SSL certificate name does not match input

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, sni, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am setting up applications on multiple subdomains on the same server - subdomain1.abc.def.com, subdomain2.abc.def.com and such. My applications are containers. I have setup a reverse proxy on my server using nginx-proxy. The server hostname is xyz.abc.def.com.

I am able to access the subdomains successfully using http. I then generated SSL certificates for both subdomains (subdomain1.abc.def.com.crt and subdomain1.abc.def.com.key; subdomain2.abc.def.com.crt and subdomain2.abc.def.com.key), and placed it under certs folder as described in nginx-proxy.

When I tried to access one of the subdomains - subdomain2.abc.def.com, the browser complains saying "the certificate name does not match input".

I have both the Common Name and SAN set to the same domain name - for e.g., the SSL certificate for subdomain1.abc.def.com has both Common Name and SAN set to subdomain1.abc.def.com.

The webserver - nginx has SNI enabled.

What am I missing in my configuration?

Comment: We don't know what's missing in your configuration since you didn't post it.

Comment: Ref. your explanation the servers hostname is `xyz.abc.def.com` which does not match `subdomain[1,2].abc.def.com` - you could terminate ssl at the proxy (e.g. encrypt traffic between users and the proxy then `proxy_pass` the connections unencrypted to the backend services) or i.e. create multiple virtual hosts each with the correct `server_name` configured with the correct certs. +1 @emix this question lacks details.